# Centering equation while placing the "for" section to the utmost right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I would like to know how I can center the equation, but place the "for i=1,...,p" to the utmost right.

```
\begin{align}
\label{meth:regular:lin:phoneydata}
\left(y_{n+j}-\sum_{k=1}^{p}x_{n+j,k}\beta_{k}\right)^{2}=\lambda\beta_{j}^{2} &&\text{for}\ i=1,\dots,p
\end{align}
```

The and symbol seems to me a bit hacky. What is the official way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside align `&` has `right` `left` alignment like

```
right & left & right & left
```

It is as simple as that.

To push `for...` to the far right, you can use `\rlap`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
right &= left & right &= left
\end{align}


\noindent
X\dotfill X\dotfill X
\begin{align}
\label{meth:regular:lin:phoneydata}
\left(y_{n+j}-\sum_{k=1}^{p}x_{n+j,k}\beta_{k}\right)^{2}&=\lambda\beta_{j}^{2} &\rlap{\text{for  $ i=1,\dots,p $}} \qquad
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think this is the first example i've seen for which it's possibly justifiable to use `align` for a single-line display.  i'll have to think about this.